# libreoffice is not executable at /usr/bin/libreoffice

Tags: php, symfony

HI I am using Docker with symfony project inside that It checks for libreoffice. I am getting the below eeror and response code is 500.

"libreoffice is not executable at /usr/bin/libreoffice"

```
if (!is_executable($this->libreOffice)) {
            $logger->critical(sprintf('[ReportTemplateService][error] libreoffice is not executable at %s', $this->libreOffice));
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('libreoffice is not executable at %s', $this->libreOffice));
        }
        $this->twigEngine = $twigEngine;
        $this->logger = $logger;
```

Can anyone help me out here.

Comment: We need more information to help you. Is the file present? Is it executable to start with. What have you tried so far? What do you want to do with libreoffice?

Comment: If the file exists, try `chmod +x /usr/bin/libreOffice`

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to PHP, or Symfony? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[is_executable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-executable.php) Returns true if the filename exists and is executable, or false on error.

Make sure the container is properly configured to [access the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55104551/how-to-access-files-in-host-from-a-docker-container)

So start checking whether `/usr/bin/libreoffice` exists, file [permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857396/file-permission-meanings/29857497), and whether it is [executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319652/check-if-a-file-is-executable). So [get into the container shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-do-i-get-into-a-docker-containers-shell), then run the following command:

```
ls -la /usr/bin/libreoffice
```

Comment: How I can check this if this is accessible from inside the container?

Comment: I already went there but I thought I am doing it wrong. So the output is 

ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/libreoffice': No such file or directory. Now the question is How can it be accessible ?

Without going inside docker I am getting this
ls -la /usr/bin/libreoffice
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Mar 15 23:42 /usr/bin/libreoffice -> ../lib/libreoffice/program/soffice

Comment: Not sure if this will help but /usr/bin/libreoffice is the folder but to execute a spreadsheet, for example you need to use /usr/bin/libreoffice -calc %f
(see https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/he/text/shared/guide/start_parameters.html)